# Можно ли передать координаты в открытую карту в браузере

Tags: java, карты, геолокация

У меня есть приложение для ПК, которое принимает от мобильных клиентов координаты их местоположения. Есть ли какие-либо механизмы, что бы можно было передать эти координаты в браузер, в котором открыта карта (яндекс или гугл - неважно), и отобразить в нем точку ? 
"Приложение для ПК" - это консольный сервер на java.

Comment: Думаю можно реализовать в вашем приложении подключения карты Яндекса или Гугла с помощью соответствующего API.

Comment: Так мне не нужно в приложение карту подключать, это просто консольный сервер, который json строки принимает. Мне бы координаты просто в браузер передать, если такое возможно..

Comment: Дополните вопрос подробностями, укажите в списке меток ЯП на котором реализовано приложение. Пишете "приложение для ПК" а сейчас говорите, что это "консольный сервер"

Comment: Извиняюсь.Сервер написан на java.